# Magento Order Grid : Retrieve quantities and products by order

Tags: magento, grid, export

I am trying to edit the Orders Grid so that I can export data to XML with the quantity of each item sold on each line.
Now I can only access the total amount of the order, which is not sufficient. I would like to build a Grid with the information available for each order in Order View > Information > Ordered items.

Is this possible with a few lines of code ?

Here is what I did for now :

I tried to manually add columns in the _prepareColumns() function from Grid.php.

Basically, I tried to add a quantity column :

```
$this->addColumn('total_qty_ordered', array(
        'header' => Mage::helper('sales')->__('Qty'),
        'index' => 'total_qty_ordered',
        'filter_index' => 'sales_flat_order.total_qty_ordered',
        ));
```

However I do not get any total quantity, and of course I do not get the product split in each order. I do not really know where to look to implement this product split.

Thanks by advance.

EDIT :

Here is what is I get thanks to the extension

[Order grid](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LaHEL.png)

However, I cannot export this product split because the last column is a kind of 'embedded' of other information. So I get an empty column in XML.

Answer (score 0):

I don't usually recommend extensions -- I believe most of them can be a bit more trouble than they are worth, but in this case, I do recommend this one:

http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/enhanced-admin-grids-editor.html

It's free -- code is fairly clean and you can add that by clicking the grid customization button on the orders page, clicking more options, then finding the items drop down and adding those columns in.   Will show you a table of all of the items.

If you want to post the code you've written the custom way, I can help you customize that to do the job too.

Comment: Hi, thanks a lot for your reply. 

I will take a look at this extension. I updated my question with what I tried to do inside Grid.php ;)

Comment: I see -- can you post the whole Grid.php file?  Did you be sure to add this line above the $this->setCollection line in _prepareCollection method?          $collection->getSelect()->joinLeft('sales_flat_order', 'main_table.entity_id = sales_flat_order.entity_id',array('total_qty_ordered'));

Comment: Yes, that worked, now I get the total quantity related to the order. I also tried your extension. I managed to add the product split for each order that I wanted, however I cannot export it to XML. I'll show you.

Comment: Just edited my question. I feel it is surprisingly complicated to get an XML with a list of ordered products while Magento is supposed to be built for e-commerce management...!

Comment: You said it worked without the extension?  If that's the case, I'd disable that and then the export should work.

Comment: No, no, the right part of my screenshot (last column) is generated by the extension. This is what I looked for, however I cannot export it.

Answer (score 0):

We published a whole blog post on how to add any data to your order grid. Hope this will help you! https://grafzahl-io.blogspot.de/2016/11/how-to-display-m2e-order-data-or.html

So the solution would be to copy the Sales Grid Block to a local module and add your column like this example:

```
$this->addColumn('order_type', array(
    'header' => Mage::helper('sales')->__('Order Type'),
    'width' => '100px',
    'align' => 'left',
    'index' => 'order_type',
    'renderer' => 'yourmodule/adminhtml_sales_grid_renderer_m2eAttribute',
    'filter_condition_callback' => array($this, '_filterM2eConditionCallback')
));
```

The filter_condition_callback is a method in the Grid Block. The renderer is another class as you can see in the namespace. In the renderer you can define what is displayed in your column. The filter_condition_callback defines how the grid should act, in case someone will filter by your custom column.

It will look like this:

```
/**
 * filter callback to find the order_type
 * of orders through m2e (amazon, ebay, ...)
 *
 * @param object $collection
 * @param object $column


* @return Yourname_Yourmodule_Block_Adminhtml_Sales_Order_Grid
 */
public function _filterM2eConditionCallback($collection, $column) {
    if (!$value = $column->getFilter()->getValue()) {
        return $this;
    }
    if (!empty($value) && strtolower($value) != 'magento') {
        $this->getCollection()->getSelect()
            // join to the m2mepro order table and select component_mode
            ->join(
                'm2epro_order',
                'main_table.entity_id=m2epro_order.magento_order_id',
                array('component_mode')
                )
            ->where(
             'm2epro_order.component_mode = "' . strtolower($value) . '"');
    } elseif(strtolower($value) == 'magento') {
        $this->getCollection()->getSelect()
            ->join(
                'm2epro_order',
                'main_table.entity_id=m2epro_order.magento_order_id',
                array('component_mode')
                )
            ->where(
             'm2epro_order.component_mode = NULL');
    }

    return $this;
}
```

As you can see, there are two joins to collect the data we need to filter for.

This is how the renderer looks like which will display the data in the grid:

```
class Yourname_Yourmodule_Block_Adminhtml_Sales_Grid_Renderer_M2eAttribute
extends Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Grid_Column_Renderer_Abstract
{
public function render(Varien_Object $row)
{
    // do whatever you need, to display your data
    // get the id of the row order data
    $orderId = $row->getEntityId();
    // get the related m2e order data
    $orders = Mage::getModel('M2ePro/Order')
        ->getCollection()
        ->addFieldToSelect('component_mode')
        ->addFieldToFilter('magento_order_id', $orderId);

    if($orders) {
        $data = $orders->getFirstItem()->getData();
        if(isset($data['component_mode'])) {
            return ucfirst($data['component_mode']);
        }
    }
    // return the string "magento" if there is no m2e relation
    return 'Magento';
}
}
```

The link will show you other example, how to show data in the order grid.